# How to avoid class and global variables

Tags: ruby, variables, memory, scope, coding-style

[Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) confirms to [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). It discourages use of anything besides instance variables. I find it confusing to not use at the least class variables. This snippet from the Style Guide frowns on usage of global variables and instead recommends *module instance variables*:

```
# bad
$foo_bar = 1

# good
module Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end

Foo.bar = 1
```

It makes sense to be wary of using global variables, but using neither global nor class variables blows my mind.

Among *module instance variables* and *class instance variables*, which is more efficient usage of memory?

For example:

**Option A (Class Instance Variable):**

```
# things that exist only with life
module Life
  # an instance of life with unique actions/attributes
  class Person
    attr_accessor :memories

    def initialize
      @memories = []
    end

    def memorize(something)
      @memories << something
    end
  end
end

bob = Life::Person.new
bob.memorize 'birthday'
bob.memorize 'wedding'
bob.memorize 'anniversary'

bob.memories
# => ["birthday", "wedding", "anniversary"]
```

**Option B (Module Instance Variable):**

```
# things that exist only with life
module Life
  # something all living things possess
  module Memory
    class << self
      attr_accessor :memories
    end
  end

  # an instance of life with unique actions/attributes
  class Person
    include Memory

    def initialize
      Memory.memories = []
    end

    def memorize(something)
      Memory.memories << something
    end

    def memories
      Memory.memories
    end
  end
end

bob = Life::Person.new
bob.memorize 'birthday'
bob.memorize 'wedding'
bob.memorize 'anniversary'

bob.memories
# => ["birthday", "wedding", "anniversary"]
```

Comment: You're mistaken. Option A is instance variable, not class instance variable. One might even say it's a "class instance instance variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the term "class instance variable". It means "instance variable on a `Class` object", not "instance variable on an instance of some class".

```
  class Person
    attr_accessor :memories # instance variable, not shared

    class << self
      attr_accessor :memories # class instance variable, shared between
                              # all instances of this class
    end
  end
```

Obviously, sometimes you do need to use class instance variables. Refrain from using class variables (`@@memories`) as they are shared between all classes in the hierarchy (the class and its children), which may lead to surprising behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Sergio.  Sounds like there are two options for variables -- instance variable (available to one instance of a class) and class instance variable (property of class object itself = available to all instances of a class). The question still remains of when to use an instance variable on the _Module_ object and when to use an instance variable on the _Class_ object?

Comment: @m8ss: for example, you might want to use module ivars when you're writing mixins ("concerns" in rails-speak)